# multiple if statements with growing logical ands

Tags: java

For an assignment in school I am doing some pattern mining through brute force (i know there are better ways, this is how it was assigned). I have come across the following situation...

```
 if (theSetLength == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
            if (itemArrays[i].getItem(theSetInt[0]) == true) ++counter;
        }
    }

    if (theSetLength == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
            if (
                itemArrays[i].getItem(theSetInt[0]) == true &&
                itemArrays[i].getItem(theSetInt[1]) == true
                ) ++counter;
        }
    }

    if (theSetLength == 3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
            if (
                itemArrays[i].getItem(theSetInt[0]) == true &&
                itemArrays[i].getItem(theSetInt[1]) == true &&
                itemArrays[i].getItem(theSetInt[2])
                ) ++counter;
        }
    }
```

This will continue up to the length of 20. Is there a terser way to write this? Specifically do I need all 20 if statements or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
    boolean all = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < theSetLength && all; ++j) {
        if (!itemArrays[i].getItem(theSetInt[j]))
            all = false;
    }
    if (all) ++counter;
}
```

The above will test the appropriate number of items depending on the value of `theSetLength`, which was defined and assigned prior to the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
int counter = 0; 

for(int theSetLength=1; theSetLength <= 20; theSetLength ++){
      for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
                for(int j=0; j < theSetLength; j++){  
                  if (itemArrays[i].getItem(theSetInt[j]) == false) break;
                } 
                if(j == theSetLength) 
                    ++counter;
            }
}
```